# mysql query to select last value in column 1 and max value from last 5 rows in column 2

Tags: mysql, sql, select, union, max

How can I select last value in Column 1 and Max value from last 5 rows in Column 2 and union them together?

For a table like this:

```
Column_1      Column_2       Timestamp
5             3000           2013-07-31 12:00:00
3             1000           2013-07-31 11:00:00
6             2000           2013-07-31 10:00:00
2             4000           2013-07-31 09:00:00
1             5000           2013-07-31 08:00:00
```

The result should be:

```
Column_1      Column_2
5             5000
```

My query is like this:

```
select COLUMN_1 from table_A order by Timestamp desc LIMIT 1
UNION
select MAX(COLUMN_2) from (select COLUMN_2 from table_A order by Timestamp desc LIMIT 0,5) as T1;
```

It throws me error: ERROR 1221 (HY000): Incorrect usage of UNION and ORDER BY

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I totally agree with @juergen d, but if you want to do this anyway you can do this using two correlated subquery in the same query like this:

```
SELECT (select COLUMN_1 
from table1 
order by Timestamp desc LIMIT 1) AS Column_1,
(select MAX(COLUMN_2) 
 from 
 (
   select COLUMN_2 
   from table1 
   order by Timestamp desc 
   LIMIT 0,5
  ) as T1) AS Column_2
FROM table1
LIMIT 1;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/efb072/2)

Answer (score 1):

Since these two selects aren't very close related - why not just make two **seperate** selects?!

It is easier and clearer in the code.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting `UNION` error because your selects don't have the same column headers. To be able to use `UNION`, your two parts have to have the same column headers, but you have `COLUMN_1` and `COLUMN_2`